# svg.js creates double SVGs

Tags: svg.js

I'm trying to use SVG.js to create an SVG, but it seems to create multiple SVG elements in my document instead of just one. I've copy-pasted the code from the SVG.js homepage (http://www.svgjs.com/) into an HTML document, but it does the same thing. Can anybody help me?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drawing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="svg.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="drawing">
    </div>

    <script>
        var draw = SVG('drawing')

        // create image
        var image = draw.image('images/shade.jpg')
        image.size(600, 600).y(-150)

        // create text
        var text = draw.text('SVG.JS').move(300, 0)
        text.font({
          family: 'Source Sans Pro'
        , size: 180
        , anchor: 'middle'
        , leading: 1
        })

        // clip image with text
        image.clipWith(text)

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I didn't, sadly. I ended up switching to http://snapsvg.io/

Answer (score 3):

The reason is simple. svg.js creates exatly 2 documents. One for displaying it and the other one is hidden and is used as a parser for different functions.
That way the lib can e.g. calculate the bounding box of an array.

Note that this parser is only created once. So even if you build up multiple svg documents there will only be one additionally doc for parsing

This is documented here: http://svgjs.dev/faq/#two-svg-s-are-generated-when-i-initialize-svg-js-is-that-a-bug

Comment: Thanks! I wish this information was available on their website and/or GitHub repository. I almost switched libs as well, assuming this was a bug.

Comment: Why you would consider it a bug when everything is working?

Comment: Because they give an example of what your markup should look like after you add an SVG with their library - and they don't show or otherwise mention the additional SVG there.